# Return blank cell if other cells have content

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to return a blank cell if either cells O2 or P2 are blank.  Both O2 and P2 have a formula linking to another cell.  Each thing that I try seems to put a number in my cell even when O2 or P2 are populated.

Cell A2 has a date, so if O2 and P2 are blank, then I return a number associated with A2, today and my network days but when O2 or P2 have a number, I want my formula to return  a blank.

=IF(OR(ISBLANK(O2),P2),"",NETWORKDAYS(A2,TODAY(),Lists!$H$2:$H$50000))

I have also tried the following with similar results to the one above:

=IF(ISBLANK(O3),"",IF(ISBLANK(P3),"",NETWORKDAYS(A3,TODAY(),Lists!$H$2:$H$50000)))
=IF(OR(O4="",P4="",ISNUMBER(O4),ISNUMBER(P4)),NETWORKDAYS(A4,TODAY(),Lists!$H$2:$H$50000),"")

The last formula gives me a blank cell but it is still showing blank even if there is no number in O2 or P2.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because both  **P2** and **Q2** have formulas, avoid `ISBLANK()`, instead:

```
=IF(OR(O2="",P2=""),"",NETWORKDAYS(A2,TODAY(),Lists!$H$2:$H$50000))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  This leaves my cell N2 empty even if there is no number in O2 or P2.

Comment: @stripey999 But that is what you asked for.................... **read your first sentence.**

Comment: Sorry about that, I just realised that I made an error in my question.  from your answer gary's student, I have modified it and it now works perfectly using the following

Comment: =IF(AND(O2="",P2=""),NETWORKDAYS(A2,TODAY(),Lists!$H$2:$H$50000),"")

Comment: @stripey999  ...................GOOD JOB.........................